# Running Skyrim under separate x session?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, wine, radeon

I am trying to run Skyrim with wine under a separate x.  It runs if I just launch it normally, but the performance is terrible so I'd like to try running it under a separate x to improve performance.

I run:

```
export WINEPREFIX="/home/john/.local/share/wineprefixes/steam"
cd "/home/john/.local/share/wineprefixes/steam/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/steamapps/common/skyrim"
xinit /usr/bin/wine TESV.exe -- :1
```

Both monitors turn black for a few seconds, then KDE comes back and I have the following in konsole:

```
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-26-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux desktop-ubuntu 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic root=UUID=a7ecd6aa-8336-41fa-8c35-44dbe80a5a41 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 04 August 2012  01:51:23AM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Aug 29 06:01:44 2012
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:1) found
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-PrHsDM/pkcs11: No such file or directory
xinit: connection to X server lost
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 9 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

waiting for X server to shut down XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server ":1"
      after 845 requests (826 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.4 and have a Redeon HD 6850 with fglrx-updates installed.  Not sure what else is relevant, but I am happy to provide more information.

What is causing this problem and what steps do I need to take to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command and run Skyrim from the terminal after you open the x session:

```
sudo xinit /usr/bin/sudo -u $USER gnome-terminal -- :1
```

Make sure you also add your user to the audio group in /etc/group if you want audio in your separate session. Edit from this:

```
audio:x:29:pulse
```

to this:

```
audio:x:29:pulse,username
```